# Oracle insert architecture

Tags: oracle, insert, dml

I have a question on the way that Oracle performs an `INSERT` action, and the reasons.

I have read that when user execute some `INSERT` - Oracle process's need to retrieve the table data.

I can understand that when user executes some select query, the instance's process need to retrieve this data from memory or from the disk (if it doesn't exists in memory).

It also make sense with an `UPDATE` operation, since the old data need to be updated, so we must read that data.

But when user execute an `INSERT` command - does it need to read any data from memory or disk files?

Is that data need in goal to create the `"before image"` of the `redo log files`?

Which data Oracle will retrieve for insert command?

I'm using Oracle 11gR2.

This is the text from the book:

> The following simple example of a row being inserted outlines how
>   Oracle processes transactions:
>
> 1. A user requests a connection to the Oracle server through a 3-tier or an n-tier web-based client using Oracle Net Services.
> 2. Upon validating the request, the server starts a new dedicated server process for that user.
> 3. The user executes a statement to insert a new row into a table.
> 4. Oracle checks the user’s privileges to make sure the user has the necessary rights to perform the insertion. If the user’s privilege
>      information isn’t already in the library cache, it will have to be
>      read from disk into that cache.
> 5. If the user has the requisite privileges, Oracle checks whether a previously executed SQL statement that’s similar to the one the user
>      just issued is already in the shared pool. If there is, Oracle
>      executes this version of the SQL; otherwise Oracle parses and executes
>      the user’s SQL statement. Oracle then creates a private SQL area in
>      the user session’s PGA.
> 6. Oracle first checks whether the necessary data is already in the data buffer cache. If not, the server process reads the necessary
>      table data from the datafiles on disk.
> 7. Oracle immediately applies row-level locks, where needed, to prevent other processes from trying to change the same data
>      simultaneously.
> 8. The server writes the change vectors to the redo log buffer.
> 9. The server modifies the table data (inserts the new row) in the data buffer cache.
> 10. The user commits the transaction, making the insertion permanent. Oracle releases the row locks after the commit is issued.
> 11. The log writer process immediately writes out the changed data in the redo log buffers to the online redo log file.
> 12. The server process sends a message to the client process to indicate the successful completion of the INSERT operation. The
>       message would be “COMMIT COMPLETE” in this case. (If it couldn’t
>       complete the request successfully, it sends a message indicating the
>       failure of the operation.)
> 13. Changes made to the table by the insertion may not be written to disk right away. The database writer process writes the changes in
>       batches, so it may be some time before the inserted information is
>       actually written permanently to the database files on disk.

Comment: where did you read this?

Comment: Expert Oracle DataBase 11g Administration by Sam Alapti.
Is that wrong?

Comment: It's not a book I know. Please post the pertinent quote. I think it may be wrong - or at least inaccurate - but it would be good to know the original point before critiquing it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the text from the book is very clear.  However, it is true that Oracle needs to read **data blocks** from disk (unless those required are already in memory) in order to insert the new row data.

In order to insert a row, the data needs to be written into a formatted data block belonging to the table.  Depending on various factors, Oracle may insert a new row into an existing data block -- in this case obviously it needs to read that block if it's not already in the cache.  If Oracle determines it is necessary to extend the table - add new blocks - that will be done in a recursive transaction; the newly allocated block(s) will need to be read into memory at some point to complete the insert.

Even if Oracle loads an existing data block that already contains row data, there should be no need for it to read the existing row data in order to complete the insert.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Oracle may very well need to perform one or more reads from disk while performing an INSERT. If the table being inserted into has a primary key defined (and all tables *should* have a primary key) the database will need to verify that the value of the primary key column(s) supplied as part of the inserted data does not match the value of the primary key column(s) for any existing row. It may be able to do this as part of the index insertion logic, which may read data from disk, but if no primary key index is defined it will have to perform a full table scan to verify that the new primary key value(s) do not already exist in the table. Similarly, if there are any foreign keys on the table the values supplied for the foreign key column(s) on the table being inserted into will need to be checked against the tables the foreign keys refer to. This will almost certainly require reading data from disk.